# how to take a screenshot of an android layout?

Tags: android

my question is how do I take a screenshot using the built in screen capture. Any hints or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Programmatically you want screenshot in android. please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways you can try,

- Using Eclipse

Open the Devices view in Eclipse ( Window Menu --> Show View Option --> Other, Android --> Devices), and there's a toolbar button on the right side labeled `Screen Capture`

- Using Android Code

  ```
  Bitmap bitmap;
  View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
  ```

Comment: then you should accept the answer by tick marking on tick mark, which is on the rightside of my answer. so it can be useful for others.

Comment: @Krish I had tried to implement the given codes of lines but it is throwing exception on third line why it is so

Answer (score 2):

Click on DDMS select emulator from left side and then click on Camera icon.. and then save into your pc..