# take a screenshot of an android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout that have inside a couple of images and I want to take all the content that appears there as an Image (Bitmap or Drawable... even if is something like png or jpg is ok). To be able to share it after. 
I try to find a solution here and I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868604/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-an-android-layout) But with this peace of code I get the screenshot of all that I have in the screen and I need to take only what appears in the layout.

Comment: In that case take screen shot and use any image tool to cut that portion.

Comment: The problem is that I am making an app to take a photo put some images and share it in facebook, twitter... so the image must be ready to use without using any image tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
```

Just got this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296711/androidtake-screenshot-and-share-it/10296881#10296881) link.I think in last night if you can adjust the height and width.It may help, but not sure.