# How to save the layout view as image or pdf to sd card in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In my application, I have a view with customer details, I want to save that view as image or PDF to SD card then print the view through third party application (Otherwise print that view directly through printer is possible).

I have no idea of how to save view as image or PDF. Can any one know please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868604/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-an-android-layout.

Comment: @HirenDabhi i get a image through this code what the link you gave,how to save it in SD card.

Comment: check this link to save you bitmap on sdcard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263375/android-saving-created-bitmap-to-directory-on-sd-card

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Use the code below

```
LinearLayout content = findViewById(R.id.rlid);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
File file,f;                    
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
    {  
         file =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TTImages_cache");
         if(!file.exists())
        {
          file.mkdirs();

         } 
         f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.seperator+ "filename"+".png");
    }
  FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);                                   
  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
  ostream.close();

 } 
 catch (Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what is the **name** in File coding in your answer.

Comment: filename is the name with which you want the image to be stored. I had used hardcoded path which i edited above.

Comment: it has to be quotes  f = new File(file, "filename"+".png");. What do you mean by run time?. You save as jpg or gif. However png is the recommended format.

Comment: thank you.finally one doubt.How to create folder and save image in that folder

Comment: file =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfolder"); if(!file.exists) file.mkdirs(). creates a folder under sdcard with myfolder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28547/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-yugesh)

Comment: @Raghunandan Hello, with your codes, it only saved the items on the current screen. Let's say I've got a list view and there is a scroll bar, am I able to save all the data of the list view into an image?

Comment: You can. There is a post on stackoberflow. But i don"t have the link

Answer (score 0):

Above code work properly but, image override because of same name so, for avoid this problem add below line:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");

Date now = new Date();

String fileName = formatter.format(now);

f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.separator+ "image_"+fileName+".png");
```